# DISTINCT not reducing two equal values to one

Tags: sql-server, distinct, system-tables

Can anyone explain the below situation, where two seemingly equal values are not reduced by `DISTINCT`?

[image: screenshot showing two values for 'SBS_UCS_DISPATCH']

The query above is `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM master.sys.dm_os_spinlock_stats where name = 'SBS_UCS_DISPATCH';`

The equivalent `SELECT name FROM master.sys.dm_os_spinlock_stats where name = 'SBS_UCS_DISPATCH' GROUP BY name;` also does the same, and adding `HAVING COUNT(1) > 1` does not yield the rows.

`@@VERSION` is *Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU13) (KB5005679) - 15.0.4178.1 (X64)   Sep 23 2021 16:47:49   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: )*

Comment: I suspect @MartinSmith is right about bad internal meta-data so this looks to be a bug. FWIW, the same occurs with SQL 2022 and Azure SQL Database. The underlying internal view query is `SELECT * FROM OpenRowSet(TABLE DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS)`.

Comment: Replicated on `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU21) (KB5025808) - 15.0.4316.3 (X64)   Jun  1 2023 16:32:31   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor) `.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like the `DISTINCT` gets optimised out during simplification.

```
select distinct name 
FROM master.sys.dm_os_spinlock_stats 
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8606,QUERYTRACEON 3604)
```

Gives

```
*** Input Tree: ***
        LogOp_GbAgg OUT(QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.name,) BY(QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.name,)

            LogOp_Project

                LogOp_Project QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.name

                    LogOp_Project

                        LogOp_StreamingTabUdfRESULT(QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.name QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.collisions QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.spins QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.spins_per_collision QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.sleep_time QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.backoffs)


                        AncOp_PrjList 

                    AncOp_PrjList 

                AncOp_PrjList 

            AncOp_PrjList 

*******************
```

Then the `GbAgg` disappears in the Simplified Tree

```
*** Simplified Tree: ***
        LogOp_StreamingTabUdfRESULT(QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.name QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.collisions QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.spins QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.spins_per_collision QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.sleep_time QCOL: DM_OS_SPINLOCKSTATS.backoffs)
```

[image]

I assume that there is some metadata indicating `name` is unique despite the query results to the contrary but I can't see how to prove that.

One way of working around this is the below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
FROM master.sys.dm_os_spinlock_stats 
WHERE name COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS = 'SBS_UCS_DISPATCH'
```

In general even if `name` was unique under one collation then it could still have duplicates with different `collate` semantics. The original column collation for me is `Latin1_General_CI_AS` so this doesn't change the case insensitive accent sensitive nature but it is enough to preserve the `GbAgg` in the plan.

[image]

```
SELECT ca.name, 
       COUNT(*) AS Count,  
       SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS [version]
FROM master.sys.dm_os_spinlock_stats 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(name COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN)) ca(name)
GROUP BY ca.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Returns the following on my dev instance

| name | Count | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LOGPOOL_FREEBUFMGR | 2 | 16.0.1050.5 |
| SBS_UCS_DISPATCH | 2 | 16.0.1050.5 |

So `SBS_UCS_DISPATCH` is not alone in being duplicated.

For me the values in the other columns are all `0` for these. So I'm unclear if the entire rows will be duplicated or not in the event that these spin locks are encountered - or whether they would need to be aggregated.

The affected types aren't ones that are documented other than "[for internal use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-spinlock-stats-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current)" anyway though.

Comment: *So I'm unclear if the entire rows will be duplicated or not in the event that these spin locks are encountered* -- I encountered it originally when I was trying to `INSERT`/`SELECT` into a history table where I had made `name` part of the PK.  I figured I would aggregate with `SUM`/`GROUP BY name` and it still happened, so I reduced it to the most straightforward example (i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT`)

Comment: *The affected types aren't ones that are documented other than "for internal use" anyway though.* -- `INSERT`/`SELECT` cares not for your "internal use" :-)

Comment: In any case, binary-collating the column is more than sufficient for *this* case -- I was more surprised that there was a property of equality that was being applied in `WHERE` that was not being applied in `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, etc.